# How to return a pretty printed string using Format.fprintf function?

Tags: ocaml, pretty-print

I am trying to understand and use  Format.fprintf for a piece of code in a module.
I have a function like this

```
let some_function fmt s = match s with
  | For(exp,_) -> Format.fprintf fmt "something here"
  | Assume x-> Format.fprintf fmt "something here as well"
```

I want to modify this function to return a string. Printf.sprintf is not an option because of some pretty printers I use in the original code. Please help.

Comment: [`Format.sprintf`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html#VALsprintf) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Format.asprintf`:

```
let string_of_s = Format.asprintf "%a" some_function s
```

I do not recommend to use `Format.sprintf` since it has a limited type.  For example the following does not type-check:

```
let string_of_s_ill_typed = Format.sprintf "%a" some_function s
```

Comment: According to the document Format.fprintf can print to a string. Can we use this feature to return a string from the above function? 

I mean using 'fprintf' to write to a string and return the same

Comment: You can use `str_formatter`, a special formatter to redirect the output of `fprintf` to a buffer instead of normal channels.  BUt it has some downsides: you need to call `flush_str_formatter` to get the string result, and `str_formatter` is a global state therefore error prone, compared to `asprintf`.